# Woo Commerce - Payment Gateway (when transaction is completed)

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I am trying to develop wordpress woo-commerce payment gateway.
After I complete transaction, here is my code.

```
`$order->update_status('on-hold',__('verifying transaction', 'woocommerce'));`
```

after the event is done, an json object gets displayed in the page

```
`{"result":"failure","messages":"","refresh":"false","reload":"false"}`
```

I try to set the result as 'success' but that failure result kept returning.
could anyone give me suggestion where I have to look at?

here is the whole code,

`$order->update_status('on-hold',__('verifying transaction', 'woocommerce'));`
`return array('result' => 'success',
    'redirect' => add_query_arg('order',$order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_pay_page_id'))))
);`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set page/page id for woocommerce_pay_page_id by using add_option('woocommerce_pay_page_id', $page_id) any where in your custom plugin.

Hope will sort out your issue.